# How to compile a wpf application as a DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

When I set the output type to Class Library, VS complains about stuff like how I don't have InitializeComponent, etc.

Winforms doesn't complain like this.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a WPF User Control Library but WPF Custom Control Library is supposed to work too. So now it works fine, I don't have to deal with strange error messages.